# airflow trigger_rule using ONE_FAILED cause dag failure

Tags: airflow

what i wanted to achieve is to create a task where will send notification if any-one of the task under the dag is failed. I am applying trigger rule to the task where:

```
batch11 = BashOperator(
task_id='Error_Buzz',
trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED,
bash_command='python /home/admin/pythonwork/home/codes/notifications/dagLevel_Notification.py') ,
dag=dag,
catchup = False
)

batch>>batch11
batch1>>batch11
```

The problem for now is when there no other task failed, the batch11 task will not execute due to trigger_rule, which is what i wanted, but it will result the dag failure since the default trigger_rule for dag is ALL_SUCCESS. Is there a way to end the loop hole to make the dag runs successfully ?

screenshot of outcome : 
[image: outcome]

Comment: The trigger_rule should set the downstream task to skipped when none of the conditions are met - which does allow for the success of the DAG itself. Can you please update with a screenshot of the outcome of your dag_run?

Comment: @andscoop  added the screenshot on question

Answer (score 1):

We do something similar in our Airflow Deployment. The idea is to notify slack when a task in a dag fails. You can set a dag level configuration `on_failure_callback` as documented https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.BaseOperator

> on_failure_callback (callable) – a function to be called when a task
>   instance of this task fails. a context dictionary is passed as a
>   single parameter to this function. Context contains references to
>   related objects to the task instance and is documented under the
>   macros section of the API.

Here is an example of how I use it. if any of the task fails or succeeds airflow calls notify function and I can get notification wherever I want.

```
import sys
import os

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from util.airflow_utils import AirflowUtils

schedule = timedelta(minutes=5)

args = {
  'owner': 'user',
  'start_date': days_ago(1),
  'depends_on_past': False,
  'on_failure_callback': AirflowUtils.notify_job_failure,
  'on_success_callback': AirflowUtils.notify_job_success
}

dag = DAG(
  dag_id='demo_dag',
  schedule_interval=schedule, default_args=args)

def task1():
  return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs!'

def task2():
  return 'cont'

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='task1',
                       python_callable=task1,
                       dag=dag)

task2 = PythonOperator(task_id='task2',
                       python_callable=task1,
                       dag=dag)

task1 >> task2
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried to use on_failure_callback in the default args like you do. Did you face the problem where it keeps sending notification non-stop after that ?  The dag was failed several times before implement on_failure_callback, so does those failed dag-runs cause the problem ?

Comment: One it sents one notification per failure. you can modify the dag id to create a fresh dag in the db.